# How to activate release profile with maven-release-plugin 3.0.0-M1?

Tags: maven-release-plugin

It seems the version 3.0.0-M1 of maven release plugin does not activate profiles for the perform goal as it did before. I configured the parameter "releaseProfiles" with "release", but it tries to activate the profile "pom.xml". Following some lines from debug log:

```
mvn release:perform -X
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:perform (default-cli) @ release-example ---
[INFO] [perform] 3/3 run-perform-goals
[DEBUG] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /data/src/gv2011/release-example/target/checkout && /programs/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -X -D maven.repo.local=/home/u01/.m2/repository -s /tmp/release-settings8879316982474805713.xml -P pom.xml install
[INFO] [WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

I put an example project at https://github.com/gv2011/release-example.

Doing the same with the previous version 2.5.3 works as expected. The corresponding log line is:

```
[DEBUG] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /data/src/gv2011/release-example/target/checkout && /programs/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn -X -D maven.repo.local=/home/u01/.m2/repository -s /tmp/release-settings14990918664891992430.xml -P release install
```

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-1038) in the version 3.0.0-M1 of the release plugin.

While the issue is closed in 3.0.0-M2, the M2 version was not released due to another critical bug. Now, we'll have to wait for 3.0.0-M3 or for the final 3.0.0 release.